# php str_replace not works

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a html code putted in a variable. I want to replace any relative image src to absolute aby using str_replace. like this:

```
$export = 'some html codes'
$repthis = 'src="/images';
$reptothis = 'src="http://images.site.com';
$export = str_replace($repthis, $reptothis, $export);
```

but this code is not working for me. I tried this code for test and it is working:

```
$export = 'some html codes'
$repthis = "text1";
$reptothis = "text2";
$export = str_replace($repthis, $reptothis, $export);
```

this code is replacing text1 by text2 in my html code correctly.
please help me.

Comment: The code looks correct. Double check your pattern. Do you exactly have `src="/images` in your original text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with how you are doing it .
You would just need to double check the input data , search string , and replacement string .

```
$inputString = '<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />';

$searchString = 'src="/images';

$replacementString = 'src="http://images.site.com';

echo str_replace( $searchString ,$replacementString ,$inputString );
```

Displayed :

```
<img src="http://images.site.com/logo.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is exactly perfect.. Double check the code or add the error.

May be you are missing semicolon (`;`) at the end of statement and missing `src="/images'`

```
$export = 'some html codes :  src="/images';
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$repthis = 'src="/images';
$reptothis = 'src="http://images.site.com';
$export = str_replace($repthis, $reptothis, $export);
echo $export;
```

**Output**

```
some html codes : src="http://images.site.com
```